# rails: table already exists on new git branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I'm trying to play around with different messaging gems that all use devise. Therefore, after installing Devise on master branch of git, I checked out a new branch to try one gem "rails messaging" https://github.com/frodefi/rails-messaging, and when I couldn't get it to work, I committed the changes to that branch, and then I went back to master and checked out a new branch to try another gem "mailboxer" https://github.com/ging/mailboxer/tree/master/lib.  In the gemfile of this new branch there was no trace of the gems from the first branch, however when I tried rake db:migrate for this second branch after installing the gems, I got this error message, which seemed to suggest that a table from the first branch was interfering with the rake of the second branch, unless by doing

```
 rails g mailboxer:install
```

It automatically runs the rake db:migrate. However, the README says that I have to run rake db:migrate, so I'm not sure...

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "conversations" already exists: CREATE TABLE "conversations" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "subject" varchar(255) DEFAULT '', "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL
```

)

Can anyone suggest how I can work around this? I don't really know what commands to run to figure this out.

This is the scheme.rb file. Based on the index "messaging users" i'm guessing it's the setup created by the rails messaging gem (on the first branch) but I'm not totally sure. I looked at the source code on git but got kinda lost because I'm not very experienced.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120302041333) do

  create_table "conversations", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "subject",    :default => ""
    t.datetime "created_at",                 :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 :null => false
  end

  create_table "messaging_users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                                 :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :limit => 128, :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",                         :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "messaging_users", ["email"], :name => "index_messaging_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "messaging_users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_messaging_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

  create_table "notifications", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "type"
    t.text     "body"
    t.string   "subject",              :default => ""
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.string   "sender_type"
    t.integer  "conversation_id"
    t.boolean  "draft",                :default => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                              :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at",                              :null => false
    t.integer  "notified_object_id"
    t.string   "notified_object_type"
    t.string   "notification_code"
  end

  add_index "notifications", ["conversation_id"], :name => "index_notifications_on_conversation_id"

  create_table "receipts", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "receiver_id"
    t.string   "receiver_type"
    t.integer  "notification_id",                                  :null => false
    t.boolean  "read",                          :default => false
    t.boolean  "trashed",                       :default => false
    t.boolean  "deleted",                       :default => false
    t.string   "mailbox_type",    :limit => 25
    t.datetime "created_at",                                       :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                       :null => false
  end

  add_index "receipts", ["notification_id"], :name => "index_receipts_on_notification_id"

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                                 :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :limit => 128, :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",                         :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

end
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that while your code, schemas, gems, and migrations are stored in git, the database itself is not. So when you switch between branches, the database still retains its state.

These solutions will all work:

1. drop and re-seed your database

   ```
   rake db:reset
   ```
2. migrate down (while on the old branch) to undo the migration. I'm not sure if the gem installed a migration in db/migrate or ran a migration directly from the gem, so this isn't as easy, but is better for data integrity if you don't want to wipe your data.
3. reload the schema you have stored in git (this has the same effects as the first one)

   ```
   rake db:schema:load
   ```
4. use an sqlite database for now - while not appropriate for production, if you check in the database to git, it will behave as you're wishing your current database behaved. I should warn you though that large files like this will be a pain. Better to use one of the other approaches.

Comment: I tried the first one (rake db:reset), but it didn't work (same error). Does the command rake db:reset include the drop within it? or am I supposed to run some other command?   Also note that I am using sqlite3, so I don't think your fourth solution is going to work.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't looked at your schema.rb closely enough. Did you check this into git on your branch before switching branches, or is it modified? (or is it not even checked into git at all?). One solution would be to `rm db/schema.rb`, then `git checkout db/schema.rb`

Comment: I ran these two commands and it didn't work. What's the point of the latter command? is it creating a new branch?  Before switching from first to second branch, I did "git add ." so I assumed it went in but maybe not...

Comment: First, don't use `git add .` as it'll almost always add files that you really don't want to add to git. Second, this only stages the file to be committed, but doesn't actually commit it to the index, so it was modified and stayed with you when you switched branches. I'd recommend issuing lots of `git status` calls to see what's been modified, as well as `git log` (or better, `git log --oneline --graph`) to get a good feel for what happens when you switch branches.

Comment: still haven't figured this out. Can you explain why I would do "git checkout db/schema.rb" and does removing db/schema destroy all the tables I've created. I only want to drop one table from a database.

Comment: I'm suggesting getting back to a known state of both the git repo and the database. First, for the git repo, make sure nothing is listed in `git status`. If something is, then you can `git reset --hard` **if you don't mind blowing away any uncommitted changes**, or you can `rm db/schema.rb`  and run `git checkout db/schema.rb` to reset just that file. These changes are just for the filesystem, so you haven't touched the database. Then to update the db, you can do a `rake db:reset` if you don't mind wiping the database.

Comment: If you can't wipe the database because it has data you need, then you'll have to look in the schema_migrations table to see which migrations have been applied, and `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=replace_with_version_number` for the one that created the table you no longer want. Since this migration is probably in a different branch, make sure you're on that branch when you migrate down.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that most db commands only affect your development environment. If you want to copy your dev db over to the test one, you have to run `rake db:test:prepare`. Common testing operations, like `rake spec` and `rake cucumber` perform this for you.

Comment: Also know that the `git checkout dir/file.rb` is not what it might suggest.   It basically says 'reset that file back to the last committed state, removing all my local edits'.  If the command was `git reset file dir/file.rb` (made this up) it would seem more logical from a function naming context.

Comment: Similar confusion is caused by the fact that making a new branch is `git checkout -b new_branch_name` - another use of the `git checkout` command that might more easily be understood if it was `git create branch branch_name`.  When you get into git more the names make more sense but when you're learning initially they often don't.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah switching branches with different migration levels is a mess. There is no 'one-liner' to do this properly. There are four things that can be out of sync. You'll need to:

1) Determine what migrations your branch has:

```
(look at the contents of db/migrations)
```

2) Determine what your app thinks your database looks like:

```
(look at db/schema.rb)
```

3) Determine what migrations your database thinks it has by looking at the `schema_migrations` table:

```
~> rails db console

(opens up your db console, in my case mysql...)

mysql> SELECT * FROM schema_migrations; # don't forget the ';' at the end!

(outputs big huge list of migration timestamps)
```

4) Look at the actual tables to see if the migrations have been applied.

```
mysql> describe table_name;

(outputs the column names, see if they have been updated per the migration)
```

5) Now the part that requires thinking. There are a couple possible scenarios. I can only speak to the one I ran into:

- Your migration files (1), your schema.rb(2) and your actual tables (4) match, but your schema_migrations table (3) is missing the migration timestamp. This was my issue.

  - If you don't care about the data: `rake db:reset`. It will trash your whole database and recreate the structure from scratch
- Please suggest other scenarios with solutions..